# AngularJS Get the document height without jquery

Tags: angularjs

As the title says, how do you get the document height?
I have tried so many things but not managed to get it.
The reason I need to do this is because I have a directive that attaches and **fixes** and element to the bottom of the page if the element is not on the page.
The height of the document can change though (due to things like accordians).
This is my directive:

```
.directive('kdActionBar', ['$timeout', '$document', '$window', function ($timeout, $document, $window) {

    // Adds the class if necessary
    var _addFixedClass = function (element, position, scrollY) {

        // If our scroll position is greater than our element position
        if (scrollY > position) {

            // Remove our class to our element
            element.removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');

            // If our scroll position is less than or equal to our element position
        } else {

            // Add our class to our element
            element.addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Fun after the page has loaded
            $timeout(function () {

                // Get our elements position
                var elementPos = element.prop('offsetTop') - $window.innerHeight,
                    documentHeight = $document.innerHeight;

                // Call our function when the page has loaded
                _addFixedClass(element, elementPos - height, $window.scrollY);

                // Bind to our window scroll position
                angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {

                    // Get our window height
                    var newHeight = $document.innerHeight,
                        newPosition = documentHeight !== newHeight ? elementPos + (newHeight - documentHeight) : elementPos;

                    // Add or remove our class
                    _addFixedClass(element, newPosition, $window.scrollY);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Try using this [function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500056/get-document-height-with-angularjs-1-2-4-not-the-body) inside the 'scroll' event.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
var w = angular.element($window);
w.height();
```